# Check if file exists in folder in c#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am moving files from source folder to destination folder. Before moving files, I am checking that directory exists or not which is working fine. The issue is with my second check where I want to make sure that folder is not empty before moving files but it is not giving me correct result.

```
public void MoveFilesFromTempToSourceTbl()
        {
            //Moving all files from temp folder to orig folder.
            string sourceFolder = (twitterDO.Path + "\\" + msgDate.Year.ToString() + "\\" + msgDate.Month.ToString() + "\\" + msgDate.Day.ToString() + "_Temp").Replace("\\", @"\");
            string destinationFolder = (twitterDO.Path + "\\" + msgDate.Year.ToString() + "\\" + msgDate.Month.ToString() + "\\" + msgDate.Day.ToString()).Replace("\\", @"\");
            string pattern = "*.txt";

            if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
            {
                if (File.Exists(pattern))
                {
                    foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder).GetFiles(pattern))
                    {
                        file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file.Name));
                    }
                }
                if (Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder).Length == 0) //Before deleting make sure that Temp folder is empty.
                    Directory.Delete(sourceFolder, true);  // Delete Temp folder after moving all the contents. 
            }
        }
```

I know I am making some small mistake but not sure what it is. Following is the screenshot of the result which I got in immediate window.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbNum.jpg

Comment: Do you need `.Count` instead of `.Length`?

Comment: I would skip the `File.Exists` check altogether. In your for-loop, if no files match the pattern, you will iterate over an empty collection (effectively doing nothing). Also, I would use `Path.Combine` to define your `sourceFolder` and `destinationFolder` variables and avoid the weird escaping.

Comment: @Cory there will be only txt files in that folder. I found one scenario where there was no files in the folder so for that I need this check.

Comment: read up on [Directory.Exist()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-exists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bit of redundancy in your current code. Starting with the if-checks, here's how I would approach this:

```
var sourceDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder); // remember this, it is reused
if (sourceDirectory.Exists)
{
    // Look for the files in the directory, if none found, will be empty array
    foreach (var file in sourceDirectory.GetFiles(pattern))
    {
        file.MoveTo(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file.Name));
    }
    // Re-check the directory for any remaining files
    if (sourceDirectory.GetFiles(pattern).Length == 0) //Before deleting make sure that Temp folder is empty.
        sourceDirectory.Delete();  // Delete Temp folder after moving all the contents. 
 }
```

As a small performance improvement, you could replace `sourceDirectory.GetFiles()` with `sourceDirectory.EnumerateFiles()` in the for-loop. This will allow you to start moving them as the method finds them, not after they have all been found.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `"*.txt"` into the `File.Exists()` call when you need to be passing a path.

[You can read the Documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

Alternatively you could use something like this:

```
Directory.GetFiles(destinationFolder).Contains(filename)
```

Comment: I tried by passing the path as well but still it returns false. If you see int screen shot I tried both ways(it is in immediate window). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user3771772 what screen shot?

Comment: See my new alternative @user3771772

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David here but also I think the flow of you logic should be adjusted a bit.  The File.Exixts(filename); should occur inside the foreach.

That will allow you to iterate each file and if it exists do something.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to check if any files exist in the location:

```
bool exist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceFolder, "*.txt").Any();
```